# Problema obtención de datos persistente en componentes

Tags: typescript, angular5

me gustaria saber que es lo que estoy haciendo de forma incorrecta ya que no puedo obtener los datos en los componentes creados (artist.component.ts). El componente album no lo pegue ya que es exactamente lo mismo que artist. Mi idea es obtener los datos de albums,artist, tracks, etc. Disculpen antes que nada, ya que soy nuevo y siento que es algo básico. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
// artist.service.ts

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { SpotifyService } from './spotify.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class ArtistService {

         artist: any;
         tracks: any;
         albums: any;
         artistRel: any;

        constructor(private _spotify: SpotifyService) {}

        getArtistDetail(id: string) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(this._spotify.getArtista(id).subscribe(artist => {
                    console.log(artist, 'Artista');
                    return this.artist = artist;
                }));
            }).then(resp => {
                this._spotify.getTop(id).map((resp:any) => resp.tracks)
                    .subscribe(tracks => {
                        console.log(tracks, 'Tracks');
                            return this.tracks = tracks;
                        });

            }).then(resp => {
                this._spotify.getAlbumsArtist(id).map((resp: any) => resp.items)
                    .subscribe(albums => {
                        console.log(albums, 'Albums');
                        return this.albums = albums;
                    });
            }).then(resp => {
                this._spotify.getRelatedArtists(id).map((resp: any) => resp)
                    .subscribe(related => {
                        console.log(related, 'Artists related');
                        return this.artistRel = related;
                    });
            }).catch(error => console.log(error, 'Something Happened...'));
        }

    }
```

> Cita en bloque

```
// artist.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArtistService } from '../../services/artist.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist',
  templateUrl: './artist.component.html'
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

  artist: {};

  constructor(public _artistService: ArtistService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['id']).subscribe(id => {
      this._artistService.getArtistDetail(id);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Intento obtenerlo de la siguiente manera
    // Aunque no funciona
    this.artist = this._artistService.artist;
  }
}
```

> Cita en bloque

```
// artist.component.html

    <div class="container top30" *ngIf="artist">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img [src]="artist.images | sinfoto" class="img-thumbnail  rounded-circle">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h1>{{ artist.name }}</h1>
                <hr>

                <a [href]="artist.external_urls.spotify" target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-success">Abrir Spotify</a>
                <button [routerLink]="['/search']" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Regresar</button>


            </div>
```

Comment: Buenas, el problema que veo es que intentas obtener los artistas en el metodo ngOnInit cuando seguramente aun no se tienen los resultados, ya que realizas la llamada getArtistDetail en el constructor, pero no estas esperando a que esta llamada haya concluido por lo que es normal que te devuelva una lista vacia.

Comment: Que tal, claro por eso mismo cuando intento un console.log me sale indefinido. Lo que trato de hacer es ver como obtener los datos en los componentes de otra manera o intentar otra forma en el servicio. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con el método "get". Especificamente hago lo siguiente:

```
  get artist() {
    return this._artistService.artist;
  }
  get albums() {
    return this._artistService.albums;
  }
```